# Многопоточность и синхронизация методов в Java

Tags: java, synchronized

Не могу понять, почему данный код не работает корректно.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Test1 extends Thread {
    public static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    synchronized void doWork1() {

        counter.incrementAndGet();
        counter.incrementAndGet();

        System.out.println("Thread+++" + " - " + Test1.counter);
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }

    }

    synchronized void doWork2() {
        counter.decrementAndGet();
        counter.decrementAndGet();
        System.out.println("Thread---" + " - " + Test1.counter);
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            doWork1();
            doWork2();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 test1 = new Test1();
        test1.start();
        Test1 test2 = new Test1();
        test2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Рано или поздно появится такая ситуация, при которой в выводе будет нечетное число. Этого, по идее, не должно происходить, т.к. методы синхронизированы, а все операции атомарны.

Answer (score 3):

При указании ключевого слова `synchronized` для методов в качестве монитора, который захватывается потоками, используется соответствующий экземпляр класса. Так как у вас два разных экземпляра класса `Test1` - потоки в принципе работают независимо друг от друга. Для того, чтобы решить эту проблему, необходимо использовать общий монитор для обоих потоков, например, отдельный объект:

```
private final static Object lock = new Object();

void doWork1() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        ...
    }
}

void doWork2() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Таким образом, потоки уже будут ждать освобождения монитора перед выполнением кода внутри блока `synchronized`.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже было отмечено выше, синхронизация в случае нестатических методов происходит по объекту, вызывающему этот метод. В данном случае есть два разных экземпляра класса `Test1`, локи захватываются на разные объекты. Решить проблему можно несколькими путями: либо захватить лок на весь класс:

```
void doWork1() {
    synchronized(Test1.class) {
        ...
    }
}
```

либо захватить лок на один и тот же объект( в данном случае можно на `counter`)

```
void doWork1() {
    synchronized(counter) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Я бы предпочел второй вариант.

Answer (score 0):

incrementAndGet - да, атомарна, но два таких оператора написанных друг за другом не являются таковыми

Вот смотри, например, один поток вошел в doWork1 и выполнил операцию counter.incrementAndGet() и в этот момент управление перешло к другому потоку который начинает выполнять doWork2 и выполняет его до конца. на его выходе получишь нечетное число.